# Scala: Automatic val initialization at compile time

Tags: scala

I am trying to create a DSL. For this DSL, users need to be able to store results in some global pool of values (I tried to think of something else, but so far I haven't been able to replace this). I'd like to create this 'pool' as an object containing all the defined values. I'd like them to be immutable, but the values themselves are secretly lists that keeps track of all the assigned values.

However, to accommodate the users as much as possible, I'd like to have something as follows:

```
object Values {
 val value1
 val value2
 val value3
}
```

This will of course not compile. But I don't want to make them to a manual assignment every time:

```
object Values {
 val value1 = X()
 val value2 = X()
 val value3 = X()
}
```

Which seems rather redundant. Everything in this object is going to be of type X anyway. I'd like to have the first version for code completion purposes (otherwise I could use Dynamic instead), but I'm not sure if that's possible and if so, how I could do that. I have looked at macro's but I'm not entirely sure yet whether those could help me or not.

Comment: macro's are "evalurated" at `compile time`. And I think what you need here are compile time things. So they can not help you here.

Comment: And what do you mean by "redundant" ? You just have to initialise things as they are supposed to be.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh: I mean redundant in the sense that it is very verbose. Every value in that object is going to be of the same type. So why should I initialize everything manually? It adds a lot of code that is not necessary in this case and makes the DSL unnecessarily verbose.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you correctly, but you can initialize all your val to the same value by `val value1, value2, value3 = X()`

Comment: @PH88, I already remembered that, but thank you! This makes it a bit more readable, but I'll still have to think about alternate solutions.